# Как передать данные из одной формы в другую на этой же странице на js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, input

Привет.

Есть форма 1:

```
<form id="form-1">
<input type="text" class="name" name="name" />
<input type="text" class="surname" name="surname" />
<input class="feedback" name="send" type="button" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

И вторая форма, открывющаяся в поп-апе по клику на кнопку:

```
<button class="btn" type="button">Оформить подписку</button>

<form id="form-2">
<input type="text" class="name" name="name" />
<input type="text" class="surname" name="surname" />
<input type="text" class="e-mail" name="e-mail" />
<input class="feedback" name="send" type="button" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Как на js (или jquery) передать введенные данные полей "имя" и "фамилия" с формы один в те же(похожие) поля "имя" и "фамилия" во вторую форму, по клику на кнопку?

```
$('.btn').click(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('#form-2 [name="name"]').val($('#form-1 [name="name"]').val());
  $('#form-2 [name="surname"]').val($('#form-1 [name="surname"]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-1">
<input type="text" class="name" name="name" />
<input type="text" class="surname" name="surname" />
<input class="feedback" name="send" type="button" value="Отправить">
</form>
<br />
<button class="btn" type="button">Оформить подписку</button>
<br /><br />
<form id="form-2">
<input type="text" class="name" name="name" />
<input type="text" class="surname" name="surname" />
<input type="text" class="e-mail" name="e-mail" />
<input class="feedback" name="send" type="button" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, дружище.

Comment: @МайклМиллер, обращайся :)